# How to check multiple string are exists in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `tags` like this:

```
/ tags
+----+------+--------------------------------------------+
| id | name |                 explanation                |
+----+------+--------------------------------------------+
| 1  | PHP  | It is a server-side scripting language     |
| 2  | C++  | It is a middle-level programming language  |
| 3  | HTML | It is a markup language                    |
| 4  | CSS  | It is a style sheet language               |
| 5  | JS   | It is a prototype-based language           |
+----+------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Also I have a string like this:

```
$str = "PHP , CSS";
```

Now I need to check whether both `PHP` and `CSS` are exist in the database? In general there is two cases:

- `True`: All tags in the string are exist in the database.
- `False`: One or more of tags in the string doesn't exist in the database.

---

I can explode that string and create a array of those tags:

```
$tags = trim(explode(",",$str)); // Array ( [0] => PHP [1] => CSS )
```

And then create multiple queries to check each of them separately:

```
$i= count($tags);
for($i; $i <= 0; $i--){
    $query .= "SELECT count(1) FROM `tags` WHERE `name` =".$tags[$i]." UNION ALL";
}
$query = rtrim($query, "UNION ALL"); // to remove last 'UNION ALL' which is redundant
```

But my approach seems really slow .. Because sometimes there is 5 tags (then there is 5 queries). Now I want to know, is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use IN('PHP', 'CSS') and check the count matches or not. Try -

```
$tags = explode(",",$str);
$tags = array_map('trim', $tags);

$query = "SELECT count(1) FROM `tags` WHERE `name` IN ('" . implode("','", $tags) . "')";
```

After executing the query match the counts.

```
if($countOfResult === count($tags));
```

Comment: If `$tags` is user input, then this query is open for sql injections.

Comment: @Daan. Agreed. But here I am just considering the `string`.

Comment: @Daan Do you have any offer how to prevent of *sql injections* for that query?

Comment: You can use prepared statements or validate the inputs properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this thing such a way. Try this:

**Your New Query:**

```
$str = "PHP , CSS";
$search = join(",", trim(explode(",",$str)));
$sql = "SELECT count(1) FROM `tags` WHERE `name` IN ($search)";
$qry = mysql_query($sql);

if(sizeof($qry) == sizeof(explode(",",$str))) 
    echo "True";
else
    echo "False";
```

I think now you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(name),name FROM `tags` WHERE name in ('PHP','CSS') group by name;
```

Comment: `name` is unique .. So I think that `group by` is redundant.